# Insert a row in mysql with a pop up on html

Tags: php, html, web

I am starting with the websites and i cant find anything similar in google(i dont know how to call it)

What i want is:

A button that when you press It, It open something like alert or pop up where you can introduce the name of an actor to insert in the datebase mysql.

I know that is strange but I need it on that way because in the same page I have an autocomplete text that sometimes you need to insert rows

Sorry about my english

Regards

Comment: Hi D4rWiNS. You should consult [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.  Your question is a topic for discussion, and does not help solve an actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a modal window. Check out Bootstrap's

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

In the `<div class="modal-body">` tag, you can place any form, and have it populated with your data.

Note there are dozens of good modal libraries, I use Bootstrap's, but there are other good ones too--check out http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin if you want a lightweight one that is not dependent on Bootstrap.